# Permalinks stopped working after migration with WP all-in-one migration plugin

Tags: plugins, permalinks, import, migration

I've used a plugin called WP all-on-one migration to migrate my website. I've also saved the permalinks twice, as instructed after the importation.

The default permalink setting works fine, but any other permalink setting results in a 404 error code (except for the home page).

Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/
Website: http://nieuw.ohmembercard.nl/

Already tried the following:
 1. Saving the permalinks twice (as instructed after importing by the plugin)
 2. Rename old .htaccess file, let the site automaticly create a new one

Comment: Probably best to check that the server can see the .htaccess file in the web root, easiest way to check quickly is to rename the one in the root of the web directory - change it to something like htaccess-old (remove the period '.' as well just to make sure) - then go back in and try and save your permalinks again, see if it creates a new .htaccess file.

Comment: I've renamed the old htaccess file, and it autmaticly created a new one. The new one has the following code:
`
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
`

While the old one just has the START WordPress and END WordPress lines.
But if i'm correct the lines starting with a # are comments in htaccess files?

Comment: The new one looks better, and yes comments start with a `#`, don't remove them as they're read by the code to figure out where to put stuff if it's being autogenerated

Comment: Even though it created a new .htaccess file automaticly, the permalinks still aren't working.

Comment: Does your server have `mod_rewrite` and is it configured to read the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, I forgot to use the AIMigration Plugin's rewrite url function - maybe this helps, given you can export the 'old' site again.

Answer (score 0):

I was migrating to Synology NAS.

Permalinks need .httaccess but this file is not used in Nginx server backend. So be sure that you have Apache server as backend when you are setting up your virtual host in the Webstation. WpAdmin will return you a success when you save permalinks but in fact nothing happen. Change to Appache and you are fine.